# Конкатенация строковых литералов разных типов

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Легально ли соединять многострочные литералы, если они имеют разный тип?

Например, обычную строку и f-строку:

```
x = ('simple'
     f'f-string {42}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, это описано в [PEP 498 – Literal String Interpolation](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/#concatenating-strings):

> Adjacent f-strings and regular strings are concatenated. Regular strings are concatenated at compile time, and f-strings are concatenated at run time. For example, the expression:
>
> ```py
> >>> x = 10
> >>> y = 'hi'
> >>> 'a' 'b' f'{x}' '{c}' f'str<{y:^4}>' 'd' 'e'
> ```
>
> yields the value:
>
> ```py
> 'ab10{c}str< hi >de'
> ```